# How to sum the value of a key across all documents in a MongoDB collection with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

i'm trying to sum up the total amount of services a user has completed using the user id and status of services. My collection looks like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: '5543333',
    title: 'service 1',
    description: 'des 1',
    status: 'completed',
    amount: 3000,
    user_id: '1',
  },
  {
    _id: '5543563',
    title: 'service 2',
    description: 'des 2',
    status: 'in progress',
    amount: 5000,
    user_id: '1',
  },
  {
    _id: '5542933',
    title: 'service 3',
    description: 'des 3',
    status: 'completed',
    amount: 4000,
    user_id: '1',
  },
];
```

Expected result: [{total: 7000}]

what i have tried:

```
db.services.aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '',
            price: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $and: [
                      { $eq: ['$status', 'completed'] },
                      { $eq: ['$user_id', user.id] },
                    ],
                  },
                  '$price',
                  0,
                ],
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            total: '$price',
          },
        },
      ]);
```

the result i'm getting: [{total: 0}]

my observation: it works with a single condition but not multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first filter out by status and then group by user_id.

Working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ESX5IAdCkeA)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$eq": [
          "$status",
          "completed"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user_id",
      "total": {
        "$sum": "$amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: it's still not working, copy pasted your solution and it is returning empty an array of object with user_id value of NULL and total value of zero

Comment: It's working in the playground. Check the playground.

Comment: Thanks. this works as long as i'm not filtering with a field referencing another collection's id. what of if i want to filter with referenced user id instead of status

Comment: Then you can do it like this, "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$eq": [
          "$user_id",
          1
        ]
      }
    }